# How to code timer which starts form 0:0:0:0?

Tags: c#

The following timer always starts from the current date. How can I change the code to start from 0:0:0:0?
So instead of displaying:

The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:31.084
The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:33.100
The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:35.100
...

it would display:

The Elapsed event was raised at 00:00:01.084
The Elapsed event was raised at 00:00:02.084
The Elapsed event was raised at 00:00:03.084
...

Thank you for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Example
{
   private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

   public static void Main()
   {
      SetTimer();

      Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
      Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
      Console.ReadLine();
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();

      Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
   }

   private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember the start time and calculate the difference to see the time spent:

```
private static DateTime start;

private static void SetTimer()
{
    //
    // set the start time
    //
    start = DateTime.Now;

    ...
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //
    // calculate the time spent
    //
    TimeSpan spent = DateTime.Now - start;

    Console.WriteLine($"The Elapsed event was raised at {spent.Hours}:{spent.Minutes:D2}:{spent.Seconds:D2}:{spent.Milliseconds:D3}");
}
```

Comment: Or if a higher resolution is needed (and available), [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) might come in handy.